# Can Bazooka Joe use Black Ops when attached to a unit?

Tags: dust-warfare

Bazooka Joe has the Black Ops special rule that allows him to be given a free order during the command phase.  The Black Ops rule is not listed as a "Shared" rule, so it is not normally given to any solider unit he joins.  Heroes become part of a squad when joined, so they can't independently receive orders anymore.

> Shared - "If at least one miniature in a unit(including Heroes) has a shared ability, the entire unit is considered to have the ability.
>
> Black Ops - "During the command phase, units with the Black Ops ability may be issued an order for free. In addition the unit may be issued an order regardless of its position on the battlefield"

When a hero is attached to a unit they are treated as part of that unit.  Any unit he is attached to wouldn't have the Black Ops ability on it's own.

Does this mean that Joe loses his Black Ops special ability while he leads a squad?

Comment: Are any of the hero abilities listed as **shared**? It appears from the rulebook that when a hero joins a squad, his abilities may affect the squad (see specific ability). All the abilities listed in the rules that could affect the squad and don't say "**does not** share" like Jump, Damage Resilent, etc. It would seem to me that the default behavior is to share abilities, unless otherwise noted. Do you have an example of one that does?

Comment: Rules like Berserk, Assault, Charge and Agile are marked as Shared. Those are all abilities that are mostly only given to Heroes.  But most of those all have a mechanical effect that would be useless if it wasn't applied to the squad as well. It kind of seems weird to have the Shared rule when everything get's shared by default.

Comment: When you say "marked as shared,"What do you mean? In the Fantasy Flight version of the rule book I never have seen this phrasing. Can you point me to tis "shared rule" you speak of? What page number does the Shared Rule appear on? Is the FF rulebook on teir website the same as the rulebook you have?

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the Dust Warfare rulebook instead of the Dust Tactics rulebook.  Shared is described on page 52 under the heading Special Abilities.  And if you look on page 53 you will see rules sometimes marked like "Air Drop - (Shared)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been errata'd in the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Dust-Warfare/Support/Dust_Warfare_FAQ_High.pdf).  Black Ops is now Shared and a unit that is joined to Bazooka Joe will automatically have the rule extended to them.